# Changing order in sankey plot

Tags: r, plot

Code for reproduction

```
library(ggsankey)
library(ggflags)
library(patchwork)
library(wesanderson)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

Data set :

```
test <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("country", "Event"), class = "factor"), 
                       node = c("JPN", "Men 50m Freestyle", "CHN", "Men 100m Freestyle", 
                                "KOR", "Men 100m Freestyle", "CHN", "Men 100m Freestyle", 
                                "CHN", "Men 100m Freestyle", "KOR", "Men 100m Freestyle", 
                                "JPN", "Men 200m Freestyle", "JPN", "Men 1500m Freestyle", 
                                "KOR", "Men 400m Freestyle", "JPN", "Men 100m Freestyle", 
                                "KOR", "Men 50m Freestyle", "KOR", "Men 1500m Freestyle", 
                                "JPN", "Men 100m Freestyle", "CHN", "Men 50m Freestyle", 
                                "KOR", "Men 200m Freestyle"), next_x = structure(c(2L, NA, 
                                                                                   2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                   NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("country", 
                                                                                                                                                   "Event"), class = "factor"), next_node = c("Men 50m Freestyle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 200m Freestyle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              NA, "Men 1500m Freestyle", NA, "Men 400m Freestyle", NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 50m Freestyle", NA, "Men 1500m Freestyle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              NA, "Men 100m Freestyle", NA, "Men 50m Freestyle", NA, "Men 200m Freestyle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              NA), Position = c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                4L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA), color = c("#00A08A", "grey60", "#FF0000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "grey60", "#F98400", "grey60", "#FF0000", "grey60", "#FF0000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "grey60", "#F98400", "grey60", "#00A08A", "grey60", "#00A08A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "grey60", "#F98400", "grey60", "#00A08A", "grey60", "#F98400", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "grey60", "#F98400", "grey60", "#00A08A", "grey60", "#FF0000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "grey60", "#F98400", "grey60")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is my code

```
#test$next_node <-factor(records_sankey$next_node,levels =c ("Men 50m Freestyle","Men 100m Freestyle","Men 200m Freestyle","Men 400m Freestyle","Men 800m Freestyle","Men 1500m Freestyle"))

#test$node<-factor(records_sankey$node,levels =c ("Men 50m Freestyle","Men 100m Freestyle","Men 200m Freestyle","Men 400m Freestyle","Men 800m Freestyle","Men 1500m Freestyle"))


f1 = "Fira Sans Compressed"

test.plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = color, label = node)) +
  geom_sankey() +
  geom_sankey_text(aes(hjust = if_else(x == "Event", 1, 0)),
                   family = f1, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, clip = "off") +
  labs(
    title = "Top 5 Asian Country's Entry (Since 1986)"
    # caption = "Total entry by event since 1986"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 23, family = f1, face = "bold"),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )

test.plot
```

I would want the output of the right-hand side to be shown according to the level and it is not working. And I also understand it is only part of the data set that I am providing. Hopefully, you guys will get the idea. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: sankey_data returns this message: `Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “Duration” is not a defined class`; could you check your inputs: copy the data and code from the question into a fresh R session to ensure it is reproducible. Thanks

Comment: have you tried plot_ly(type = "sankey"?  I 've found it simpler to use than ggplot for controlling the position of nodes.

Comment: I have edit the code and it should  now be able to reproduce the code.